# request.patch gives duplicate value found error for a Salesforce API

Tags: python, salesforce, python-requests

I have referred [this guide](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_upsert.htm) to make patch request to a salesforce api.

My python code :

```
headers = {"Authorization" : "OAuth %s"%str(accessToken), "Content-Type" : "application/json"}
try:
    response = requests.patch(url, data, headers=headers)
    self.log.info('request.patch response : %s %s'\
                 % (response.text, response.status_code))
except Exception, e:
    self.log.info("Exception %s"%str(e))
```

I am updating a record that already exist in salesforce. But I am getting below error -

```
response.text = [
  {
   "message":"duplicate value found: mypackageprefix__external_field__c duplicates value on record with id: a1T50000005G9jxyz",
   "errorCode":"DUPLICATE_VALUE",
   "fields":[]
  }
]
response.status_code = 400
```

When does this error occur?

Also, as I am only updating the existing records, ideally I should only get `status_code=204` (like the guide says) But I have been getting `status_code=201` sometimes. Why?

Please help me out.

Comment: status 400 means bad request. Something is wrong in your request. Something like an ID or a content-type.

Comment: I randomly get this error for some requests only. My code works fine for many requests. I don't see any issue in content-type too.

Comment: what was the URL you sent the request to, and what did the payload look like?

Comment: Check the comments on @vincent's answer

Answer (score 0):

400: This means bad-request. The documentation you gave us says:

*Note that if your relationship type is master-detail and the relationship is set to not allow reparenting, and you try to update the parent external ID, you will get an HTTP status code 400 error with an error code of INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE.*

201: This means created. The documentation says:

*HTTP status code 201 is returned if a new record is created.*

204: This means the response has no content. The documentation says:

*HTTP status code 204 is returned if an existing record is updated.*

Other Words: 400 (Something is wrong) 201 (It didn't exsist yet, but it does now) 204 (It did exsist and it is now updated)

Comment: I am not getting error code `INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE`. I got `DUPLICATE_VALUE`. Please can you explain what you said about that error. I did not understand that.

Comment: What url are you using?

Comment: It depends. For oauth i request an access token using a refresh token. From that response I get an instance url. Using that i create my url. E.g instance url - Na1.salesforce.com

Comment: I mean what request gives that response?

Comment: url = `instanceUrl + "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/" + packagePrefix + "package__c/" + packagePrefix + "external_field__c/" + externalField`, data = `{packagePrefix + 'status__c' : status}` and headers from my question

Comment: It seems you trying to update something that should be unique